# cMake cannot find BOOST_TIMER_LIBRARIES

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have boost installed. I am trying to compile a project that has the following line in the cmake line :
`target_link_libraries(
    tiscos_stat
    ${Boost_TIMER_LIBRARY}`

This is causing issue while compiling :

`CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_TIMER_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)`

I installed boost on my ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

I have a timer.hpp in my usr/include/boost folder

Why is this happening ? Do I need to install some more libraries ?

Please help.

EDIT:

Here is the output with running cmake with the `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` flag

```
`r@r-HP-Mini-110:~/l33t/freeln/raijin_world/source/raijin/build-debug$ cmake ../ -DBoost_DEBUG=ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:525 ] Boost not in cache
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:528 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:530 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = ON
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:532 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:534 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:536 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:538 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:606 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:608 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:610 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:612 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:614 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:696 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:715 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.46.1
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:808 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc47
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:818 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:861 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:863 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:906 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/boost/boost_1_46_1/lib;/boost/boost_1_46/lib;/boost/lib;/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_date_time-gcc47-mt;boost_date_time-mt-1_46_1;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_date_time-gcc47-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-gcc47-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-gcc47-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_program_options-gcc47-mt;boost_program_options-mt-1_46_1;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_program_options-gcc47-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_program_options-mt-d;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_serialization-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_serialization-gcc47-mt;boost_serialization-mt-1_46_1;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_serialization-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_serialization-gcc47-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_serialization-mt-d;boost_serialization-mt;boost_serialization
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_system-gcc47-mt;boost_system-mt-1_46_1;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_system-gcc47-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for TIMER_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_timer-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_timer-gcc47-mt;boost_timer-mt-1_46_1;boost_timer-mt;boost_timer
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for TIMER_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_timer-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_timer-gcc47-mt-d;boost_timer-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_timer-mt-d;boost_timer-mt;boost_timer
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_thread-gcc47-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_46_1;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_thread-gcc47-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:977 ] Searching for UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_unit_test_framework-gcc47-mt-1_46_1;boost_unit_test_framework-gcc47-mt;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-1_46_1;boost_unit_test_framework-mt;boost_unit_test_framework
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1009 ] Searching for UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_unit_test_framework-gcc47-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_unit_test_framework-gcc47-mt-d;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-d-1_46_1;boost_unit_test_framework-mt-d;boost_unit_test_framework-mt;boost_unit_test_framework
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1119 ] Boost_FOUND = FALSE
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1202 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.46.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_timer

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)


-- Configure C++ compiler options for GNU
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_TIMER_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
`
```

Comment: /usr/include/boost/timer.hpp is from the original (now deprecated) library.  The [new library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html) was introduced in version 1.48.0 I believe.  It resides in boost/timer.  Try running `cmake . -DBoost_DEBUG=ON` and paste the output in your question to give us a bit more info on what could be going wrong please.

Comment: @Fraser Do I need to install 1.48 ? If yes, how can i do so since using the apt-get installs 1.46 by default.

Comment: @Fraser I edited the question with he additional details

Comment: Yes, you need 1.48 minimum.  The install instructions for Unix are [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Comment: @Fraser Thanks, why dont you add that as an answer !

Comment: Sure thing - just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your debug output, it appears that CMake is finding Boost version 1.46.1.  The [Boost.Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/timer/doc/index.html) library was upgraded in 1.48.0 and you need the upgraded version.

To install the current version of boost, refer to the [Getting Started on Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) page of the docs.